Coroutine in Unity isn't working correctly
I'm beginner in Unity and i have an problem.
In Update function , i call  StartCoroutine(move());
That is my move function:
 public IEnumerator move()
 {
     Vector2 tmp = new Vector2(14.47f, transform.position.y);
     bool hasReachedTarget = false;
     while (!hasReachedTarget)
     {
         if (transform.position.x < tmp.x)
         {
             transform.position =
                 Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, tmp, moveSpeed * 0.01f * Time.deltaTime);
             yield return null;

         }
         else
         {
             hasReachedTarget = true;
         }
     }
     Debug.Log("ct "+count);
     count++;
     if (!isHandled)
     {
         isHandled = true;
         transform.position = tmp;
         GameStoryManager.curGameStoryIndex++;
         animator.SetBool(IS_MOVE_NAME, false);
     }
 }

My problem is when when this function run, it call to it call to it  a lot of times;
By use Debug.Log("ct "+count) , i see a lot of count.
I don't know why did it happen. Please someone explain it to me. Thanks for yours answer.

because every update you are starting a new instance of the coroutine?

I am curious: Why are you using a coroutine for this? If you have a specific reason that is ok, you can follow the other comments, but know that, if you replace the while with an if, and the return yield null with return and put the code directly inside Update it should work fine and you won't need the coroutine.

@BugFinder Thank for your answer, i added some conditions in update function to call only startCoroutine  one time and it worked.

I realized that the reason is i call move function directly in update funtion, thus it start new instance of coroutine every update function is called. I add some condition to call move function and it worked.

Well, you call this function in the update function.
Naturally, the function is called continuously and momentarily.
And the condition (transform.position.x < tmp.x) is not satisfied.
In this case you ReachedTarget = true; However, when your function is called again by the update function, hasReachedTarget = false; And this scenario continues like this and that is why your message is printed.
The message should not be printed only if your object's x-axis position is less than 14.47, which it apparently isn't.
Sorry for my poor English.
It's Google Translate's fault. :)

Some of the variable names are wrong and there seems to be some confusion between assignment and comparison.
